# How to insert into database 3 arrays files on 3 field

Tags: codeigniter, upload

i have a problem in my try project on upload multiple image.
I can't just use a fixed number of file to upload. I tried many many solutions on StackOverflow but I wasn't able to find a working one..

my table format on database :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJUhV.png)

Here's my Upload controller

```html
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

   class Upload2 extends CI_Controller {  
     public function __construct() {  
       parent::__construct();  
                         $this->load->helper(array('url','html','form'));  
       $this->load->model('m_upload');
                 }  
         function index(){  
                 $this->load->view('upload_form');  
         }  
         function upload() {  
                 if($this->input->post('upload'))  
                 {  
       $foto = array();
                         $number_of_files = sizeof($_FILES['userfiles']['tmp_name']);  
                         $files = $_FILES['userfiles'];  
                                 $config=array(  
                                 'upload_path' => './uploads/', //direktori untuk menyimpan gambar  
                                 'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif',  
                                 'max_size' => '2000',  
                                 'max_width' => '2000',  
                                 'max_height' => '2000'  
                                 );  
                         for ($i = 0;$i < $number_of_files; $i++)  
                         {  
                                $_FILES['userfile']['name'] = $files['name'][$i];  
                                $_FILES['userfile']['type'] = $files['type'][$i];  
                                $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $files['tmp_name'][$i];  
                                $_FILES['userfile']['error'] = $files['error'][$i];  
                                $_FILES['userfile']['size'] = $files['size'][$i];  
                                $this->load->library('upload', $config);  
                                $this->upload->do_upload('userfile');
        $foto[] = $this->upload->data();
        $data = array(
        
             //$data[$parts[0]] = isset($parts[1]) ? $parts[1] : null;
             'foto'       => $foto[0]['file_name'],
             'foto_ktp' => $foto[1]['file_name'],
             'foto_npwp' => $foto[2]['file_name']
             
           );
           //$this->m_upload->m_upload($data);
           $result_set = $this->m_upload->insert($data);
       
                         }  
                 }  
                         $this->load->view('upload_success');  
         }  
 }
```

My upload form is This.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
  <head>  
    <title>Tutorial CodeIgniter with Gun Gun Priatna</title>  
  </head>  
  <body>  
  <h2>Upload Gambar</h2>  
    <?php echo form_open_multipart('index.php/upload2/upload'); ?>  
      <table>  
        <tr>  
          <td>FILE 1<input type="file" name="userfiles[0]" /></td>
          <td>FILE 2<input type="file" name="userfiles[1]" /></td>
          <td>FILE 3<input type="file" name="userfiles[2]" /></td>
        </tr>  
        <tr>  
          <td><input type="submit" name="upload" value="upload"></td>  
        </tr>  
      </table>  
    <?php echo form_close();?>  
  </body>  
 </html>
```

how to fix insert 3 file into database above..thank u very much..

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting in the loop, you want to insert after the loop when you have *all* the files.

PHP:

```
function upload() {
    if (!empty($_FILES['userfiles']['name'])) {
        $foto = array();
        $number_of_files = count($_FILES['userfiles']['tmp_name']);
        $files = $_FILES['userfiles'];
        $config = array(
            'upload_path' => './uploads/', //direktori untuk menyimpan gambar  
            'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif',
            'max_size' => '2000',
            'max_width' => '2000',
            'max_height' => '2000'
        );
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $foto = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_files; $i++) {
            $_FILES['userfile']['name'] = $files['name'][$i];
            $_FILES['userfile']['type'] = $files['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $files['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['userfile']['error'] = $files['error'][$i];
            $_FILES['userfile']['size'] = $files['size'][$i];
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
                show_error($this->upload->display_errors());
            }
            $foto[] = $this->upload->data('file_name');
        }
        $data = array(
            'foto' => $foto[0],
            'foto_ktp' => $foto[1],
            'foto_npwp' => $foto[2]
        );
        $this->m_upload->insert($data);
        $this->load->view('upload_success');
    } else {
        show_error('No files uploaded!');
    }
}
```

HTML:

No need for `userfiles[2]` just call them `userfiles[]`

Comment: Oh ya..thank you for your answer..
But I want the insert file display to be 3 input 1 submit, like my form

Comment: and what exactly is happening?

Comment: and the result is
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 1

Filename: controllers/Upload2.php

Line Number: 77

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\asset\application\controllers\Upload2.php
Line: 77
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\asset\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once